# Регулярное выражение (группировка совпадений)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как правильно группировать совпадения?

```php
$text = "
    { bool0 ?
        { bool1 ? t : f } :
        { bool2 ? a : b } : nothing
    }
";

preg_match_all($reg, $text, $match);
```

---

Хочу получить массив c совпадениями:

`$match[1]` `bool0`
`$match[2]` `{ bool1 ... } : { bool2 ... }`
`$match[3]` `nothing`

---

Остановился на этом выражении, но оно не даёт нужного результата

```
"/{ (\w+) \?(?:[^{}]|(?:([^:](?0)|(.*})\s*:\s*)))*}/"
```

---

Нужно найти совпадения между первым знаком `?` `($match[2])` и последним `:` `$match[3]`. Третья группа совпадений может отсутствовать, как и последнее двоеточие.

Если выражение находит фигурную скобку внутри, то скобка должна обязательно закрываться.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111886/discussion-on-question-by-doofy----).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как в каждой строке ожидается только одно совпадение, вам подойдёт следующее выражение:

```
(?s)^\s*{\s*(\w+)\s*\?\s*(.*?)(?:\s*:\s*({[^{}]*}|\S+))?\s*}\s*$
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/xFjtfe/2).

**Подробности**

- `(?s)` - флаг, разрешающий точке находить также переносы строки
- `^` - начало текста
- `\s*{\s*` - символ `{`, слева и справа от которого может быть 0 и более пробельных символов
- `(\w+)` - Группа №1: одна и более букв, цифр или символов нижнего подчёркивания
- `\s*\?\s*` - символ `?`, слева и справа от которого может быть 0 и более пробельных символов
- `(.*?)` - Группа №2: ноль и более любых символов, как можно меньше
- `(?:\s*:\s*({[^{}]*}|\S+))?` - необязательная нехахватывающая группа, которая находит

  - `\s*:\s*` - символ `:`, слева и справа от которого может быть 0 и более пробельных символов
  - `({[^{}]*}|\S+)` - Группа №3: `{`, ноль и более символов, отличных от `{` и `}`, а потом `}`, или один и более символов, отличных от пробельных символов
- `\s*}\s*` - символ `}`, слева и справа от которого может быть 0 и более пробельных символов
- `$` - конец текста.